# How can I perform when-then/ if- else in jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular7

I want to perform a validation like if a value is selected accordingly its mapped url should be used. This validation is performed in a component as a function.
How can I test this component in jasmine?

```
it('should return correct mapping to cluster and url',()=>
  {
    clusterSingleton= ClusterDetailSingleton.getInstance();
    clusterSingleton.setclusterName('dataForUser');
    clusterSingleton.setmanagerUrl('/angular/get')
    expect(clusterSingleton.getclusterName()).toBe('dataForUser');
    expect(clusterSingleton.getmanagerUrl()).toBe('/angular/get');
  })
```

The output should be if `dataForUser` is selected then the `'/angular/get'` url must be used.

Comment: what is the error that you're getting? Is your component making a web request and you want to wait for it to complete before `expect` statements ?

Comment: yes i am making web request and i want to check - if i have selected sandbox then the url mapped to sandbox url is sent.

Comment: Could you please post your code snippet which makes the request and the error that you're getting